# Clustering with Google Trends

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I have question about Data mining in R using google trends. I tried doing some research into it and it is hard finding material on this. I also tried doing k-mean clustering but I had no success. I found this clustering code on this site, but it does not work.I was wondering if I could get some help with it.I get object hc/d not found error. If you have an easier solution to getting clustering easier, let me know or maybe point me to some resources. I appreciate the help!

```
set.seed(1)
library(gtrendsR)
library(dtw)


gconnect("user@gmail.com", "pass")
lang_trend <- gtrends(c("data is", "data are"), res="7d")
plot(lang_trend)

cotton_trend <- gtrends(c("cotton", "satin", "velvet"), res="7d")
d <- dist(t(cotton_trend$trend[, -(1:2)]), method="DTW")
hc <- hclust(d)


par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(cotton~end, cotton_trend$trend, type="l", ylim=range(cotton_trend$trend[, -(1:2)]), col=3, ylim="")
for (x in 4:ncol(cotton_trend$trend)) lines(x=cotton_trend$trend$end, y=cotton_trend$trend[, x], col=x)
legend("topleft", names(cotton_trend$trend)[-(1:2)], lty=1, col=3:ncol(cotton_trend$trend))
plot(hc)
rect.hclust(hc, k=2)


cutree(hc, k=2)
```

Comment: Please ,can you execute this script line by line, and tell us wich line gives you this error, i executed your script and i did not get your error.